# On StackExchange site account deletion the user is directed to the "page not found" page

Tags: bug, status-completed, redirection

The user's account is still deleted on that StackExchange site, but upon deletion the user is directed to the "page not found" page. The user should likely be redirected to the home page of that StackExchange site instead. It hurts nothing functionally, but just to improve the user interaction it's probably best to change this.

I noticed this first on the [Unix & Linux Site](http://unix.stackexchange.com) then I tested it on another site ([Personal Finance](http://money.stackexchange.com)) and got the same result.

Comment: So when clicking the "delete" button in your profile it sends you to page not found, not the home page?

Comment: @BenBrocka , Correct.

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah, that's a buggy workflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The next build will redirect users to a site's home page after self-deletion, rather than just reloading.